# Why does my page keep reloading despite event.preventDefault ()?

Tags: typescript, forms, preventdefault

Whenever I want to call my functions either with the button or with Enter, the page reloads even though I have set `event.preventDefault ()`. How can I stop my page from reloading?

A part of my HTML:

```
<form>
        <input id="vornameInput">
        <button id="vornameButton">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

A part of my Typescript:

```
let vornameInputfield: HTMLInputElement;
let vornameButton: HTMLButtonElement;
let personenListe: PersonenListe;
let ulListe: HTMLUListElement;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentloaded', function () {
    vornameInputfield = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('vornameInput');
    vornameButton = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById('vornameButton');
    ulListe = <HTMLUListElement>document.getElementById('personenListe');
    personenListe = new PersonenListe();


    vornameButton.addEventListener('click', function (event: MouseEvent) {

        let vorname: string = vornameInputfield.value;
        event.preventDefault();

        if (vorname.trim().length !== 0) {
            personenListe.addPerson(vorname);
            vornameInputfield.value = "";
        }
    })

    const ENTER_KEY = 13
    vornameInputfield.addEventListener('keyup', function (event: KeyboardEvent) {
        event.preventDefault();

        if (event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY) {
            let vorname: string = vornameInputfield.value;
            if (vorname.trim().length !== 0) {
                personenListe.addPerson(vorname);
                vornameInputfield.value = "";

            }
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: It would be much easier to add an event listener to the form's submit event instead of trying to prevent all possible interactions that might submit the form.

Comment: **All:** It's a typo. `DOMContentloaded` => `DOMContentLoaded` (capital L). The code within the loaded callback isn't running at all.

Comment: As @GuyIncognito said, hooking the `submit` event would be a simpler way to avoid submission. Even *simpler* would be `type="button"` on the button. :-)

Comment: Forms want to be submitted, and they will use whichever button they can. You can set type="button" on a button to prevent  it from being treated as type="submit" - but then you need to submit your form another way. Looking at your code, it seems like you might be better off trimming your input on change, instead of waiting for the form to be submitted and trying to do it then. Finally - why not just avoid using a form? It's designed to submit itself - but it's not that difficult to control the post yourself, and it means you don't have to fight what the browser is trying to do.

Comment: Thank you guys! Your suggestions for improvement helping me a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're preventing the default events for `click` and `keyup`, but what you want to prevent is the default `submit` event on the form.

Add an id to the form as you did for the input and button:

```html
<form id="vornameForm">
        <input id="vornameInput">
        <button id="vornameButton">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Then, get it with the code and prevent the default submit event on the form:

```
let vornameForm: HTMLFormElement;
//...

document.addEventListener('DOMContentloaded', function () {
    vornameForm = <HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById('vornameForm');
    //...

    vornameForm.addEventListener('submit', function(event: Event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    //...
})
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it helped. Have a look at the comments people are writing to the original post, they have valuable information